# Query parameter in Ember Route

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Is there a way to have query parameter in ember routes. In my app there is a product search route where the user search for products with an input field. When the user navigates to one of the found products and then hit the back button the previous search is gone cause the url of the route is `products`. So is there a way to store the query the user does into the route like `products?search=shirts` so the previous result will be displayed when the user comes back to this page?

Comment: There's an [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1773) for this. But I think you could do this without query string. How are you doing it currently? can you share some code?

Comment: I doesnt. When the user reloads the page the last query is gone. Maybe I could change the route to `products/search/shirt` or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood what you want or unless I have to because of biz requirements, I wouldn't create a route for specific search category, instead I would create a computed property (or a function with `observe`) that is filtered by a search keyworkd (as a property of my controller). Something like the following:

```
App.SomeController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    searchKeyword: '',
    filteredSearchResults: function() {
        var keyword = this.get('searchKeyword');
        if(keyword.length > 0) {
            // filtered search
            return this.get('content').filter(function(item) {
                // do your own filtering logic here
                return item.get('name').indexOf(keyword) !== -1
            });
        }  else {
            // unfiltered search
            return this.get('content');
        }
    }.property('content', 'searchKeyword');
});
```

Then in Handlebars I would iterate somewhat like this

```
{{#each filteredSearchResults}} 
    ... do stuff here...
{{/each}}
```

The search text field should be bound to the controller's `searchKeyword` property, so the search term doesn't get lost when you transition from route to route. The problem with this is that the search term will not get erased unless you explicitly go and clean that property ( you could technically have some logic/checks for specific scenarios in which you manually delete the value of that field/bind);

Comment: But the problem with this solution is, that you cant link to a search result. After all the query need to be stored into the url.